# Extrema Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, maxima-minima

$f(x,y)=x^2+x\cdot y+x+y^2$ on the set $S=\{(x,y) : x^2+y^2 \leq 9\}$.

I found the critical point on the interior of $S$ to be $\left(\frac{-2}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right)$.

I'm not sure how to parametrize the boundary of $S$ in terms of theta using sine and cosine and write $f$ in terms of theta on the boundary by putting restrictions on theta.

I also am not sure how to find the extrema of $f$ on $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

You can let $x = 3\cos \theta$ and $y = 3\sin \theta$, then they satisfy $x^2+y^2=9$. Make this substitution to $f$ and your optimization problem will become a single variable problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use $$\sin(\theta)=\frac{y}{r}$$ and $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{x}{r}$$ where $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: but how does that help you write f in terms of theta on the boundary and how would you use that to find the extrema of f on S?

Comment: this was not my question!

Comment: I'm aware that x^2+y^2=9 is parametrized by x=3cos(theta) and y=3sin(theta). But, it is an inequality as given and I'm not sure how to proceed from there...

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 < 9$ in the interior of the region and $x^2 + y^2 = 9$ on the boundary.  And then you can convert to polar to analyze the boundary.